# What does condition tag do in hyperledger composer for .cto?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Hey guys I am new to hyperledger composer, I have been following their tutorial on for creating the CTO models. I don't understand the what the condition tag is used for?
For an example,

```
 rule R3_TradersSeeOwnHistoryOnly {
  description: "Traders should be able to see the history of their own transactions only"
  participant(t): "org.example.trading.Trader"
  operation: READ
  resource(v): "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"
  condition: (v.participantInvoking.getIdentifier() != t.getIdentifier())
  action: DENY
}
```

"This rule restricts the current Trader participant to seeing only transactions he/she invoked on the blockchain."

What is the purpose of condition tag in general and specifically in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

the condition is like a 'WHERE' clause - ie a way to control access (allow/grant, deny etc) to records on the blockchain ledger - just like authorization controls you would see in applications or databases (for example) to limit 'what records' someone is allowed to see or do something with.

Specifically the condition:

```
condition: (v.participantInvoking.getIdentifier() != t.getIdentifier())
```

says that 'restrict a Trader to only READ transaction info (historical records on the ledger) that they initially submitted (invoked)' - ie they can't see OTHER Trader's records, which is implicitly DENIED by default.